# How to output only column names with a certain prefix in jsp?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

**My use-case**
I'm trying to output a list of strings in jsp, Those String are column names.

I don't know in advance what the list will contain for example: it may have "id", "_firstname", "_lastname" and so on, or it may have "id", "_salary" and so on.

This list is filled with all column names of a certain table, based on tablename.

**What I have done so far**
Using `foreach` i can dynamically populate the list. Then I want to output this list in JSP, with or without JSTL, I'm using Spring anyway) I pass this list into the model. and it's ok.

**My Question**
I want to output all the fields EXCLUDING the id, I can manage this with the `<c:choose>` and index.
However, I heard there is another way, somehow checking for prefixes in tableNames. 
As you can see, all the necessary fields have an "_" prefix before their names. Where can I find information on how to use it to filter what fields get shown?

Comment: Share your list which you are getting from Database. I am sure the list you are populating will clarify and describe most part of your question. Which Database you are using? What you mean by * prefix as mandatory? Where you can see * as prefix? In Database or on jsp?

Comment: I guess the question rendered wrong, I was never expecting to write a star, but instead an underscore. The look of the prefix doesn't matter, let's say it is a v_columnName; The list itself is a basic List<String> which has columnNames. Actually I'm sharing not only this list. It is a custom structure which has 2 fields: List<Strin> as columnNames and List<List<String>> as valuesInRows (the internal list being values in 1 row) but it is secondary here. Let's imagine I'm passing just one List<String> tableNames.

Comment: Wouldn't - if (columnname.contains("mandatory_prefix") { do something} - work for you?

Comment: Thank you! I actually used startsWith but it works anyway! Now may I ask a related question, I have another List<String> in he same jsp (actually the internal list of that List<List<String>> and it contains values. the length is always the same as in the columnNames list. How do I rememeber the columnNames I showed so that I show now the corresponding values?

Comment: Put up a separate question showing all your Controller, Entity(ies), Services, DAO, JSP etc what you have come up with so far. It will help the contributors to understand your problem/situation better and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, I have resolved it by creating a list of indexes before jsp and passing it to model

Comment: Structure the question in a logical manner to make it easier to read and understand